# Android: Multiple webservice calls running parallely using asynctask

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Hi i would like to know how to run Multiple webservices calls parallely, Actual scenario is when my app first starts for the first time i have to call 4 different webservices  and fill the database before the user can interact with my app. can someone suggest what will be the best approach for doing this.
Also how to use AsyncTask for running this 4 webservice calls .

As of now i am doing one webservice call in my homeActivty using the async task

```
new DownloadJSON(HomeActivity.this).execute();  

public class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private static Context context;
        public DownloadJSON(Context context){
            this.context = context;
                }
        @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    try {
        startWebServiceData();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
        return null 
}
void startWebServiceData() throws IOException {
     String URL = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    String SOAP_NAMESPACE = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    String METHOD_NAME = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    String SOAP_ACTION = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
    SoapObject soapObject;

    soapObject  = new SoapObject(SOAP_NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envp = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
     envp.dotNet = true;

     envp.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);
     System.out.println("soapObject===>"+envp.bodyOut);
     HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
     try {
     androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envp);
     SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envp.getResponse();
     String result = response.toString();
     System.out.println("response data from server====="+result);
     parseJson(result);
     } catch (Exception e) {
        }}

private static void parseJson(String result) {

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Can someonepoint me in right direction

Comment: Instantiate it 4 times and implement multiple callbacks?

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán can u be more specific. please

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán this will slow down my app i guess ..

Comment: `new DoSomethingAsync1().execute();new DoSomethingAsync2().execute();new DoSomethingAsync3().execute();new DoSomethingAsync4().execute();`It won't slow anything, as those are running out of UI Thread.

Comment: @SergiCastellsaguéMillán .Will try that, is this only the way,or any other approach?

Comment: can i use THREAD_POOL Executor for my tasks.???

Answer (score 0):

Could you use doInBackground method params,

```
new DownloadJSON(HomeActivity.this).execute(<PropertyValue1>); // first property
new DownloadJSON(HomeActivity.this).execute(<PropertyValue2>); // second property
new DownloadJSON(HomeActivity.this).execute(<PropertyValue3>); // third property
new DownloadJSON(HomeActivity.this).execute(<PropertyValue4>);  // fourth property

public class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<PropertyInfo, Void, Void> {

    private static Context context;
        public DownloadJSON(Context context){
            this.context = context;
                }
        @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(PropertyInfo... params) {

    try {
        startWebServiceData(params[0]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
        return null 
}
void startWebServiceData(PropertyInfo propertyValue) throws IOException {
     String URL = "xxxxxx";
    String SOAP_NAMESPACE = "xxxxx";
    String METHOD_NAME = "xxxxx";
    String SOAP_ACTION = "xxxxx";
    SoapObject soapObject;

    soapObject  = new SoapObject(SOAP_NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    soapObject.addProperty(propertyValue); 

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envp = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
     envp.dotNet = true;

     envp.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject);
     System.out.println("soapObject===>"+envp.bodyOut);
     HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
     try {
     androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envp);
     SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envp.getResponse();
     String result = response.toString();
     System.out.println("response data from server====="+result);
     parseJson(result);
     } catch (Exception e) {
        }}

private static void parseJson(String result) {

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: what are these params[0], please explain more

Comment: params array contains your Url, namespace, methodname and soap action values. Ex. params[0] url, namespace equals params[1], method name params[3] and saop action params[4]

Comment: The issue is the url namespace,soapaction are same for all websercice calls ,only the propertyInfo value changes.

Comment: What's propertyInfo value?

Comment: i will be sending propertyInfo values to my SOAP request   PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
     pi.setName("isMonth"); 
     pi.setValue(false);             
     soapObject.addProperty(pi);
     PropertyInfo pi2= new PropertyInfo();
     pi2.setType(PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS);
     pi2.setName("catgoryNumber");
     pi2.setValue(1); 
     soapObject.addProperty(pi2);

Comment: Got some idea with your above code..can u please tell me where to change my code

Comment: Now your async task look like ASyncTask<PropertyInfo,Void,Void>, doInBackground(PropertyInfo...params) and startWebServiceData(PropertyInfo propertyValue).

Comment: if you dont mind can u edit you answer, and mention the params.thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38871/discussion-between-teekib-and-nurisezgin)